# Use json_decode() to create array insead of an object

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to decode a JSON string into an array but i get the following error.

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Here is the code:

```
$json_string = 'http://www.example.com/jsondata.json';

$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata);
print_r($obj['Result']);
```

Comment: It would have worked if you accessed with `$ob->Result` instead.

Answer (score 975, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://php.net/json_decode), you need to specify `true` as the second argument if you want an associative array instead of an object from `json_decode`.  This would be the code:

```
$result = json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

If you want `integer` keys instead of whatever the property names are:

```
$result = array_values(json_decode($jsondata, true));
```

However, with your current decode you just access it as an object:

```
print_r($obj->Result);
```

Comment: It begs the question, what are the advantages of having it return as an array and not an object?

Comment: It raises the question. To "beg a question" means to assume something that remains to be proved ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question)). In either case, the advantage might be that the OP is more comfortable traversing arrays than objects, or that some other, already implemented, code requires an array.

Comment: @jamesnotjim The default implementation that returns an object could beg the question that objects are better return values than arrays, could it not?

Comment: Indeed it could @DavidMann. Touché!

Comment: I would add the comment (albeit years later) that there is no possibility of JSON containing anything but data making this a confounding "default" choice.

Comment: What do you mean? It's an option about whether you get the json objects with string keys presented as php objects of stdClass or associative arrays.

Comment: perform statement $array = array_values($array); if you want indexed array insted of associative one.

Comment: JSON is Javascript _Object_ Notation, and it describes data objects. I suppose that is the rationale behind the default choice. I agree, however, that an associative array is often more useful in PHP. It's just not a thing that exists in terms of JS/JSON.

Comment: Old post but this totally helped me out!

Answer (score 49):

try this

```
$json_string = 'http://www.domain.com/jsondata.json';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($obj);
```

Answer (score 31):

This is a late contribution, but there is a valid case for casting `json_decode` with `(array)`.
Consider the following:

```
$jsondata = '';
$arr = json_decode($jsondata, true);
foreach ($arr as $k=>$v){
    echo $v; // etc.
}
```

If `$jsondata` is ever returned as an empty string (as in my experience it often is), `json_decode` will return `NULL`, resulting in the error **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 3**. You could add a line of if/then code or a ternary operator, but IMO it's cleaner to simply change line 2 to ...

```
$arr = (array) json_decode($jsondata,true);
```

... unless you are `json_decode`ing millions of large arrays at once, in which case as @TCB13 points out, performance could be negatively effected.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case you are working on php less then 5.2 you can use this resourse.

http://techblog.willshouse.com/2009/06/12/using-json_encode-and-json_decode-in-php4/

http://mike.teczno.com/JSON/JSON.phps

Answer (score 6):

According to the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) `json_decode` function has a parameter named **assoc** which convert the returned objects into associative arrays

```php
 mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = FALSE ] )
```

Since **assoc** parameter is `FALSE` by default, You have to set this value to `TRUE` in order to retrieve an array.

Examine the below code for an example implication:

```php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

which outputs:

```php
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This will also change it into an array:

```
<?php
    print_r((array) json_decode($object));
?>
```

Comment: This a waste of CPU/Memory, as suggested `json_decode($object, true);` the `true` does exactly the same, internally much faster.

Comment: @TCB13 except if you need both and don't want to run decode again

Comment: Concur with @JimmyKane . I tried and run both versions in a cycle; if you need both object and array (albeit this ought to happen rarely?), `json_decode` + casting is 45% faster than running both flavours of `json_decode`. On the other hand, both are so fast that unless you need literally *thousands* of decodings, the difference is negligible.

Answer (score 5):

```
json_decode($data, true); // Returns data in array format 

json_decode($data); // Returns collections
```

So, If want an array than you can pass the second argument as 'true' in `json_decode` function.

Answer (score 4):

`json_decode` support second argument, when it set to `TRUE` it will return an `Array` instead of `stdClass Object`. Check the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) page of `json_decode` function to see all the supported arguments and its details.

For example try this:

```
$json_string = 'http://www.example.com/jsondata.json';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata, TRUE); // Set second argument as TRUE
print_r($obj['Result']); // Now this will works!
```

Answer (score 4):

**I hope this will help you**

```
$json_ps = '{"courseList":[  
            {"course":"1", "course_data1":"Computer Systems(Networks)"},  
            {"course":"2", "course_data2":"Audio and Music Technology"},  
            {"course":"3", "course_data3":"MBA Digital Marketing"}  
        ]}';
```

**Use Json decode function**

```
$json_pss = json_decode($json_ps, true);
```

**Looping over JSON array in php**

```
foreach($json_pss['courseList'] as $pss_json)
{

    echo '<br>' .$course_data1 = $pss_json['course_data1']; exit; 

}
```

**Result**: Computer Systems(Networks)

Answer (score 2):

in PHP json_decode convert json data into PHP associated array

For Ex: `$php-array= json_decode($json-data, true);
print_r($php-array);`

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
<?php
$json_string = 'http://www.domain.com/jsondata.json';

$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata, true);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($obj['Result']);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
$json_string = 'https://example.com/jsondata.json';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata);
print_r($obj->Result);
foreach($obj->Result as $value){
  echo $value->id; //change accordingly
}
```