# How to convert URL encoded JSON array into PHP array

Tags: php

how can convert URL encoded JSON sent from my android application into PHP array.Current format i am getting looks like below format.

```
[{\\\"product_id\\\":\\\"33\\\",\\\"amount\\\":\\\"1\\\"},{\\\"product_id\\\":\\\"34\\\",\\\"amount\\\":\\\"3\\\"},{\\\"product_id\\\":\\\"10\\\",\\\"amount\\\":\\\"1\\\"}]
```

How can i convert those data into below format

```
product_id    amount
   33         1 
   34         3 
   10         1
```

Because i want to insert those data into MySQL database.Can anyone please help me regarding this problem.

Comment: $jsonArray = json_decode($jsonStr, TRUE); 
Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array

Comment: What are these endless backspaces there for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_decode(jsonencoded string, TRUE)` is correct way to encode json string.

But your json string encoded too deeper and recursive. your json encode string should as below

```
[{"product_id":9,"amount":500},{"product_id":9,"amount":500},{"product_id":9,"amount":500}]
```

Other wise, you will get NULL value

Answer (score 2):

Use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) :

```
echo json_decode($jsonarr);
```

Comment: @Damith, this means that the json passed to it cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit as explained in the php manual.

Answer (score 2):

this can be done by  [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$json = '{"foo": 12345}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo'}; // 12345
```

**Good read**

--- [common mistakes using json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#example-3489)