# How to get JSON data in ajax.php page?

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am sending email using ajax JSON.

Code:

```
var lookup = {
            'name': fname,
            'email': email,
            'items': [{
                'message': message,
                'value': itemValue
            }]
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: JSON.stringify(lookup),
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

My data is going to JSON format

```
{"name":"Chinmay","email":"xxxxxxxx@gmail.com","items":[{"message":"Bla Bla Bla!!!","value":"100"}]}
```

In my ajax.php page how to get the `name`, `email`, `message` and `value`?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: hello @kingkero i have tried 1hr but not solved my problem

Comment: ok, so first lookup [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). You made a `POST` request with `lookup` (which jQuery automatically converts, so you can safe some code). Now I look up sth like ["_php post_"](http://bit.ly/MzqCWe) and am already linked to [the official manual on `$_POST`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: [Decoding JSON as associative arrays instead of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're posting the data as JSON, you have to deserialize the [raw post data](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php):

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
echo $data['name'];
...
```

Comment: not working. coming error message `<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: name in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\2014\ebay\ajax.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />`

Comment: still coming error `<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\2014\ebay\ajax.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />`

Comment: We're getting there.. try again :)

Answer (score 0):

That is not going to work. The `data` argument needs key - value pairs, so you could do something like:

```
data: {json_string: JSON.stringify(lookup)},
```

and in php:

```
$data_array = json_decode($_POST['json_string']);
```

Although normally you would just send the form to your php (if possible) file without having to build the data-structure yourself:

```
data: $('form').serialize(),
```

and then in php you can do something like:

```
$name = $_POST['fname'];
```

Comment: This one also not working. error message `<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: json_string in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\2014\ebay\ajax.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />`

Comment: Yes i have changed my javascript and php page

Comment: Hi @jeroen I got my answer your code showing blank array `array(0) {
}` when i am using `var_dump($_POST);` Thanks for trying.