# How to iterate through array of dictionary in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php
    exec("./mycode.py", $out)
    var_dump($out) 

?>
```

It produces the following output:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(28) "{"ky2": "bar", "ky1": "foo"}" [1]=> string(30) "{"ky2": "bar2", "ky1": "foo2"}" }
```

How can I iterate the output above and print the result?

```
 Entry 0
    ky1 - foo
    ky2 - bar
 Entry 1
    ky1 - foo2
    ky2 - bar2
```

They Python code (`mycode.py`) is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
dict1 = {'ky1':'foo', 'ky2':'bar'}
dict2 = {'ky1':'foo2', 'ky2':'bar2'}
print json.dumps(dict1)
print json.dumps(dict2)
```

It prints this:

```
{"ky2": "bar", "ky1": "foo"}
{"ky2": "bar2", "ky1": "foo2"}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [json\_decode to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need a a foreach loop in conjunction with `json_decode()` on this one. While inside the loop, decode them each time. Consider this example:

```
$out = array(
    array('{"ky2": "bar", "ky1": "foo"}'),
    array('{"ky2": "bar2", "ky1": "foo2"}'),
);

$new_out = array();
foreach($out as $key => $value) {
    $values = json_decode($value[0], true); // <-- second parameter
    // set to TRUE to force return as an array
    ksort($values);
    $new_out['Entry '.$key] = $values;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_out);
echo '</pre>';
```

Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [Entry 0] => Array
        (
            [ky1] => foo
            [ky2] => bar
        )

    [Entry 1] => Array
        (
            [ky1] => foo2
            [ky2] => bar2
        )

)
```

Edit: Or just maybe you just want an echo, I dont know.

```
foreach($out as $key => $value) {
    $values = json_decode($value[0], true);
    ksort($values);

    // or just plain echo
    echo "Entry $key <br/>";
    foreach($values as $index => $element) {
        echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5) . "$index - $element <br/>";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Entry 0 
   ky1 - foo 
   ky2 - bar 
Entry 1 
   ky1 - foo2 
   ky2 - bar2
```

[**Sample Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vge07d)

Comment: @JakeGould Thank you for pointing that out, I forgot to explain what that second parameter means.

Comment: @kevinabelita: Thanks so much. Could you kindly advice the construct right from `exec()` output? Coz, I tried but prints nothing.

Comment: @pdubois can you rephrase it? i dont understand, you want construct that kind of output right after `exec()`?

Comment: @kevinabelita: in your example you have this `$out = array(array('{"ky2": "bar", "ky1": "foo"}'),array('{"ky2": "bar2", "ky1": "foo2"}'),);
` How can I convert `$out` of  to that construct from `exec("./mycode.py", $out)`

Comment: @pdubois you dont need to construct such value, it just created my own copy of `$out` which is also the same output of your executed python script. the one you provided should be fairly the same as the one i used on m example.

Comment: @kevinabelita: Thanks but why this code http://dpaste.com/17CD9YC/ prints nothing?

Comment: @pdubois is that your real code? some are missing semicolons `;`

Comment: @pdubois i havent coded any python script yet, but i think youre not calling the python script correct. isn't it `python scriptfile.py`, without `./`