# PHP: Separate 2 or more values of 1 key in Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array came from my ajax

```
$contestant_name_arr = $_GET['contestant_name_arr'];
print_r($contestant_name_arr);
```

Whenever i try to get the value of each in loop i got error because instead of this

```
Array ( [0] => value1,value2 )
```

It should be look like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => value1 
    [1] => value2
)
```

How do I separate like that in the example above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Convert comma separated value pair string to Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830374/php-convert-comma-separated-value-pair-string-to-array)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either devise your url query string to be:

```
http://yourhost.com?contestant_name_arr[0]=value&contestant_name_arr[1]=value2
```

Or just simply `explode`;

```
$contestant_name_arr = explode(',', $contestant_name_arr[0]);
```

Comment: You can also leave out the numbers and do this:  `http://yourhost.com?contestant_name_arr[]=value&contestant_name_arr[]=value2`. PHP will automatically number them.