# How to separated string with ',' and store it in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, yii2

I am trying to get values from input box and then separated text with `,` and make it in array and after store it in database.

> page save with the name of 'index.php'

There is Form

```
<form action="index.php" method=post>
   <td>checking array implode</td>
   <td><input name="implo" type="text"  /></td>
</form>
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: the opposite of `implode()` is `explode()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Convert comma separated value pair string to Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830374/php-convert-comma-separated-value-pair-string-to-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP `explode` function in order to separate your input by given delimiter. In your case it would be something like this:

```
$array = explode(',', $_POST['implo']);
```

After that you can do a `foreach` with the array and run `INSERT` queries in your database.

Here's also a reference for the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML part:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
 <td>checking array implode</td>
  <td><input name="implo[]" type="text"  /></td>
</form>
```

PHP part:

```
$implo = explode(',', $_POST['implo']);
```

`$implo` variable will be something like this: `"first_value,second_value,third_value..."`