# How to get values from a json response array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json response like following

```
{"name":['abc','def','ghi','jkl']}
```

How can i extract each of those names in php?

```
expected out put :

abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

Comment: json_decode($json) will do that

Comment: Please start with reading manuals for `json_decode` function and basic array operations.

Comment: can anyone tell me d answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array

Comment: I think the answer already there, you just have to do more research.http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Answer (score 1):

Use  `json_decode` and

See this link
[function.json-decode.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
   $jsons=array('name'=>array("abc","def","ghi","jkl"));  
   foreach($jsons as $json ){
        foreach($json as $val){
            echo $val  .'<br>';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
<?php
 $var = '{"name":["abc","xyz"]}';// here will be your response
  $arr = json_decode($var);
 foreach($arr->name as  $key=>$value)
 echo $value."<br/>";
 ?>
```