# How to put this JSON to array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm beginner in PHP so please limit criticism. I've got a JSON (returned from server) that I can't put to array. I've read this: [json_decode to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array) and other topics but that JSON make only errors, and I don't have any ideas to fix it.

Here is JSON:

```
{"ProductID":"1","result":[{"options":"1"},{"data":[{"Amount1":";option no 1;option no 2"},{"Amount2":";option no 1;option no 2"},"Amount3":";option no 1;option no 2"},{"Amount4":";option no 1;option no "},"Amount5":";---"},{"Amount6":";---"},{"Amount7":";---"},{"Amount8":";---"},"Amount9":";---"},{"Amount10":";---"},{"Amount11":";---"},{"Amount12":";---}]}]}
```

Comment: If you go to a [json linter site](http://jsonlint.com/) (which also pretty prints the json for you) you can see the json is invalid.

Comment: Your JSON seems invalid.

Comment: Also, http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: Thanks everyone, especially @JimL. That site is this I need :)