# How can I get an array element out of an array in the value of a form element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have an html form element with its value set as an array. I want to get one of these values out of the array via jQuery. How is this done? Here is my code. Maybe it can speak for itself if my explanation wasn't clear. Thank you!

```
    var lat = 0;
    var long = 0;

    //gets the latitude and longitude when a user clicks on any place on the map

    map.on('click', function(e) {
        lat = e.latlng.lat;
        long = e.latlng.lng;

    //store the lat and long in an array

        var latlong = [lat, long];

    //here I am setting the value of my an element in my form as the array of lat and long

        document.getElement(".<?= $this->getName() ?>").set("value", latlong);
        var getLatlong = jQuery(".<?= $this->getName() ?>").val();
        console.log("retrieved: " + getLatlong);

    //it saves and retrieves properly.

    //THE PROBLEM IS HERE
    //THE PROBLEM IS HERE
      var lat = $(".<?= $this->getName() ?>").val()[0];
      var long = $(".<?= $this->getName() ?>").val()[1];
    //THE PROBLEM IS HERE
    //THE PROBLEM IS HERE


    });
```

This all runs fine but I do not get the reuslt I want. If i try using any of the lines of code below

```
    //THE PROBLEM IS HERE
      var lat = $(".<?= $this->getName() ?>").val()[0];    //returns 9
      var long = $(".<?= $this->getName() ?>").val()[1];   //returns 4
      var long = $(".<?= $this->getName() ?>").val()[3];   //returns 2
      var long = $(".<?= $this->getName() ?>").val()[4];   //returns 3
    //THE PROBLEM IS HERE
```

to get either the latitude or the longitude "ie: 94.2323, 12.9932"

```
The index [0] returns 9,
the index [1] returns 4,
the index [3] returns 2
```

as if the 94.2323 is the array instead of the lat and long as the array. I want [0] to return 94.2323, and [1] to return 12.9932.

I tried explaining this and formatting this question the best I could. Thank you.

Comment: You are defining the same variables over and over? Don't do that. Use new variable names instead. JavaScript actually runs all `var` statements first, before the rest of the code (within that scope), regardless where in the code block you define them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert `Array` to `JSON` format

```
document.getElement(".<?= $this->getName() ?>")
.set("value", JSON.stringify(latlong));
```

`JSON.parse()` to convert `JSON` formatted `String` to `Array`

```
var getLatlong = JSON.parse(jQuery(".<?= $this->getName() ?>").val());
console.log(getLatlong[0], getLatlong[1]); // do stuff
```

Comment: ok this works in Javascript. Thanks a ton. Though it doesn't completely solve the issue I am trying to solve. How might I write this in PHP?

Comment: $info->latitude = $_REQUEST["mapquestlocation"][0];
        $info->longitude = $_REQUEST["mapquestlocation"][1];

Comment: What does `php` return for `latitude`, `longitude`?

Comment: Those two lines result in "Unexpected token o in JSON at position". Im trying to hit my save button and put those lats and longs in the database. but I am unable to get lat and long out of the elements value attribute. Im pretty new to php so Idk if I am saying this clear enough.

Comment: How are the values sent to `php`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, via a hidden input.                                             <input name="<?= $this->getName(); ?>" class="<?= $this->getName() ?>" value="<?= $this->getValue() ?>" type="hidden" />
                                                                                          document.getElement(".<?= $this->getName() ?>").set("value", JSON.stringify(latlong));

Comment: Have you tried using `json_decode` ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array

Comment: $info->latitude = json_decode($_REQUEST["mapquestlocation"])[0];
        $info->longitude = json_decode($_REQUEST["mapquestlocation"])[1];