# Parse JSON in string format via PHP

Tags: php, json, import.io

I have a json file from import.io that returns null when decoded, but shows up as a string when encoded and is all there. How can I "loop" through a json string in PHP?

Json data is very lengthy so I refrained from posting it.

Json: https://codeshare.io/2BD4ma

Code:

```
<?php

$jsonFile = file_get_contents('feeds/quotes.json');

//decode
$results = json_encode($jsonFile, TRUE);

var_dump($results);


?>
```

Comment: maybe answered previously? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array

Comment: post sample json and sample code that you tried

Comment: have a look at http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/decode.php

Comment: added samples to post

Comment: You need to _decode_, not _encode_!

Comment: Doesn't work with newline delimited json

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to see the code you are using, or have tried....

Either way, you need to use `json_decode` on the JSON object, which will turn it into a PHP array:

```
$data = json_decode($yourJsonData);

// print_r it to see:
print_r($data);

// to loop through it, you could do:
foreach ($data as $item)
{
    print_r($item); // used print_r: unsure if this data will contain nested objects/arrays
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the data is null everytime I use decode.

Comment: THat doesnt look like properly formatted JSON. Are you sure its not been serialized / escaped somewhere in the process..?

Comment: Not sure there is anyway to tell. It is automatically generated by import.io

Comment: Can you post the endpoint / URL that you are getting the JSON from..?

Comment: here you go:  http://importio.desk.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2471525-json-response and https://data.import.io/extractor/eff120be-7eec-4211-a808-53f12d46353a/json/latest?_apikey=bfdc92eb3b02401da6c1213e42161835f41855043513e60ac53a96e9c3c17ffdee65f3b4ed5a6e0ebeeea3a741c25573e8891bf1df067e478a4f0c96a44124dcd7c6c95148299d9f3c89fe3d7b9c45a6

Comment: Ok, so the data returned from data.import.... is perfectly valid JSON, you should have no trouble in using `json_decode` there. In your example, where does feeds/quotes.json get its data from? The same place you just posted?

Comment: the same file; it is just local to the server rather than being fetched each time

Comment: Interesting, because the output of data.import.io... is different to JSON in the codeshare you posted.  i.e if you go to the codeshare URL and save the json file, then run json_decode on it, it will work...

Comment: using the method in the article that I posted yields roughly the same results - I get unexpected token errors

Comment: safe to say i am not using node either.

Comment: may give up on this one; can't wrap my head around how to get it to parse correctly.

Comment: It seem, as though the json you are getting is a bunch of json objects separated by new lines.  Looking at the docs (http://importio.desk.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2471525-json-response) they also mention this too. Try splitting the data you get on new lines, then json_decode each item?

Comment: any idea how I can go about achieving this? Just need a point in the right direction at least.

Comment: Also, what is the separator for each of these lines?