# How to use json_decode in php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to use this code:

```
 <?php  echo json_decode('"\uD83D\uDE00"'); ?>
```

When I am using this code I am getting this value :

But when I am trying to use this code using some variable like this:

```
 <?php
 $var = "\uD83D\uDE00";
 echo json_decode('"{$var}"');
 echo "{$var}";
 ?>
```

I am getting this as output:

```
 {$var}\uD83D\uDE00
```

I have tried many things but nothing is working what can be the best way to do this.

Comment: how this is showing output:  <?php  echo json_decode('"\uD83D\uDE00"'); ?> here I am asking about some basic php concatination.

Comment: `'$var'` print `$var`  while `"$var"` print value of `$var` Note the outer single and double quote

Comment: echo json_decode('"$var"'); this code is giving me this value $var

Comment: this works <?php  echo json_decode('"\uD83D\uDE00"'); ?>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json\_decode to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange as demand but funny, try this :)

```
<?php
    $var = "\uD83D\uDE00"; 
    echo json_decode('"'.$var.'"');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <?php
    $var  ='"\uD83D\uDE00"';
      echo json_decode($var); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
  <?php 
     $var = "\uD83D\uDE00";
     echo json_decode($var);
     echo $var;
    ?>
```