# Object Change into Array using Php

Tags: php

I want to change this

```
    {"success":true,"data":{"transactionid":"83ad87ef-711a-4123-8273-92684daab934","messageid":"U3HuUCokq0PzvH0L7cIWiQ2"}}
{"success":true,"data":{"transactionid":"83ad87ef-711a-4123-8273-92684daab934","messageid":"U3HuUCokq0PzvH0L7cIWiQ2"}}
```

Into array using PHP... Please guide..

Comment: Always, Always, Always search stackoverflow before posting a question.  This will save the community and moderators the trouble of flagging and killing your questions.

Comment: Whoops, that's JSON object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array

Comment: Will search more from next time... thanks for you ideas...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert you `json` into `array` using `json_decode()` function with second parameter as `true`.Like this..

```
$json = '{"success":true,"data":{"transactionid":"83ad87ef-711a-4123-8273-92684daab934","messageid":"U3HuUCokq0PzvH0L7cIWiQ2"}}';
$array = json_decode($json,true);

print_r($array);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [transactionid] => 83ad87ef-711a-4123-8273-92684daab934
            [messageid] => U3HuUCokq0PzvH0L7cIWiQ2
        )

)
```

For more see docs [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: This is how it should be done... thanks...:)

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks.. it was helpful..:)