# I want to populate my WordPress website with a json file. How can that be done?

Tags: json, wordpress, jsonparser

This is the json format:

```
{
    "Album": [
        {
            "name": "despacito",
            "lang": "spanish",
            "thumbnail": "some-url",
            "scrn":"some-url",
            "ourl":"some-url",
            "YearOfRelease": 2017
        }
    ]
}
```

How can this JSON be displayed on a WordPress site. Please do share if there is any tutorial on this or try to help me doing this.

Answer (score 0):

***Using PHP***
Decode the json object using **json_decode($obj)**
refer : [Decoding json in php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
{
            "Album": [
                {
                        "name": "despacito",
                        "lang": "spanish",
                        "thumbnail": "some-url",
                        "scrn":"some-url",
                        "ourl":"some-url",
                        "YearOfRelease": 2017
                    }


         ]
         }
```

to retrieve name, use
$obj->Album->name

### OR

```
foreach($obj-> Album as $value){
  echo $value->name; //change accordingly
}
```

Sources : [json_decode to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array)

Comment: Ok but, How can i display the data on my site?? It would be great if you can help me with that.

Comment: use :foreach($obj-> Album as $value){
  echo $value->name; //change accordingly
}