# Change API Response to an array in PHP

Tags: php, api

I have an API which is returning me response like this.

```
{
    "logs": [
        [
            "2018-05-22 00:10:16", 
            "Billed"
        ]
    ], 
    "package": "superpremium", 
    "subdate": "2018-05-08 14:18:18", 
    "submedium": "CALL"
}
```

I'm trying to change into array so It can be easily accessible for me. For example.

```
$response['subdate']; // echo 2018-05-08 14:18:18
$response['submedium']; // echo CALL
$response['package']; // echo superpremium
```

and the logs one should be like

```
$response['logs'];
```

logs must be an array so I can use `foreach` log to display all values of an array like `2018-05-22 00:10:16` or "Billed" etc

I have used below codes but returns empty screen.

```
json_decode($response, true);
json_decode($response);
```

Comment: so what you've tried till now ? and I'm sure if you are looking into json to array php you will find something

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json\_decode to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array)

Comment: I have used json_decode but returns empty

Comment: @Kaddath doesnot work

Comment: json seems incorrect because of `,` at last:-https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: well, yes it does work. It just means you have something else going wrong in your code or your JSON. Is your variable `null`? it could indicate an error in the JSON parsing, and in this case using `json_last_error_msg()` you can have the eventual error

Comment: Yes it is returning `:null` when i do var_dump..

Comment: What code are you *actually* running? Because you haven't posted anything that would display any output - you're just running `json_decode` and not doing anything with the result, so a white screen is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to change into array

Just [cast](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) it into one then:

```
$response = (array) json_decode($response);
```

After that, you can easily access `$response['subdate']` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode($your_response)` method. Your json data will get converted to arrays.

Like:

```
$response = json_decode($api_response);
```

And then you can access the values as (By seeing your data, seems that you are getting object):

```
$subdate = $response->subdate; // echo 2018-05-08 14:18:18
$submedium = $response->submedium; // echo CALL
$package = $response->package;
```

Comment: I have used `$response= json_decode($response);` but it returns empty, nothing else.

Comment: It seems like you are getting object instead of Array, so you can access data by `$response->subdate`, `$response->submedium`.... like this

Comment: I have tried `$response->submedium` but it is giving me this error `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Try var_dump(), you will get idea about which type of output you are getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171751/discussion-between-sambhaji-katrajkar-and-valar-m).

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_data = json_decode($YourJSONResponse, true);
```

Then these will be available:

```
$json_data["package"]
$json_data["subdate"]
$json_data["submedium"]
```

Answer (score -3):

Please change date from:

```
"submedium": "CALL",
```

To:

```
"submedium": "CALL"
```

Remove char "," and used function json_decode it, and enjoy

Comment: I can't see how this answers the question. The example code doesn't have a trailing comma.

Comment: @Lex there was one. The OP edited without adding a notice to the question

Comment: @Kaddath I was wondering if that may be the case. In another comment above the OP mentions he put it there bu mistake.