# Take values from JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I am doing something wrong but I cannot figure it out.

**I have this JSON**

```
$data = {  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "app_min_temp":15.5,
         "valid_date":"2018-08-10",
         "weather":{  
            "icon":"c02d",
            "code":801,
            "description":"Few clouds"
         },
         "max_temp":26.3,
         "datetime":"2018-08-11"
      },
      {  
         "app_min_temp":18.5,
         "valid_date":"2018-08-11",
         "weather":{  
            "icon":"c02d",
            "code":801,
            "description":"Few clouds"
         },
         "max_temp":26.3,
         "datetime":"2018-08-11"
      }
   ],
   "city_name":"Berlin"
};
```

**Expected Result**
And trying to get the values from app_min_temp and valid_date and print them all together. Something like

```
app_min_temp:15.5 valid_date: 2018-08-10 Weather description: Few clouds
app_min_temp:18.5 valid_date: 2018-08-11 Weather description: Few clouds
```

**FOREACH**
I am trying to foreach trougn the json like this

```
$json = json_decode($data);
foreach($json as $data) {
        echo "app_min_temp: ".$data[0]->app_min_temp.PHP_EOL."valid_date: ".$data[0]->valid_date.PHP_EOL."Weather description: ".$data[0]->weather->description.PHP_EOL; //etc
    }
```

**The Results**
But I am getting strange result with only the first set of data printed. Like:

```
app_min_temp: 15.5
valid_date: 2018-08-10
Weather description: Few clouds

app_min_temp: 
valid_date: 
Weather description: 
app_min_temp: 
valid_date: 
Weather description: 
app_min_temp: 
valid_date: 
Weather description: 
app_min_temp: 
valid_date: 
Weather description: 
app_min_temp: 
valid_date: 
Weather description: 
app_min_temp: 
valid_date: 
Weather description:
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `data` key in your JSON object you need to access first. Also, the array index access is done by `foreach` already.

```
foreach ($json->data as $row) {
   echo "app_min_temp: ".$row->app_min_temp;
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew that I am missing something general. Just couldn't spot it

Answer (score 1):

Another solution based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array) post where it says that "if you want an associative array instead of an object from json_decode" you should do this way:

```
$json = json_decode($data,true);  // CHANGE

foreach($json['data'] as $data2) {
        echo "app_min_temp: ".$data2['app_min_temp'].PHP_EOL.
            "valid_date: ".$data2['valid_date'].PHP_EOL.
            "Weather description: ".$data2['weather']['description'].PHP_EOL; //etc
}
```

The **true** flag means *returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.*

Answer (score 1):

You missed the nesting in JSON data. Your $data and json's data are totally different. I changed your loop section a bit . And the output was as you expected.

```
 <?php
$data = '{  
  "data":[  
   {  
     "app_min_temp":15.5,
     "valid_date":"2018-08-10",
     "weather":{  
        "icon":"c02d",
        "code":801,
        "description":"Few clouds"
     },
     "max_temp":26.3,
     "datetime":"2018-08-11"
  },
  {  
     "app_min_temp":18.5,
     "valid_date":"2018-08-11",
     "weather":{  
        "icon":"c02d",
        "code":801,
        "description":"Few clouds"
     },
     "max_temp":26.3,
     "datetime":"2018-08-11"
  }
],
"city_name":"Berlin"
}';

$json = json_decode($data);

foreach($json->data as $data) {
    echo "app_min_temp: ".$data->app_min_temp.PHP_EOL."valid_date: ".$data-   >valid_date.PHP_EOL."Weather description: ".$data->weather->description."<br>"; 
}
?>
```

**Output**

```
app_min_temp: 15.5 valid_date: 2018-08-10 Weather description: Few clouds
app_min_temp: 18.5 valid_date: 2018-08-11 Weather description: Few clouds
```