# How to convert JSON string to arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, database

With php, I need to convert json arrays into arrays, what should I do, json_encode didn't work for me, thanks in advance for help.

//json sequence

```
[
  {
   "name":"Menu",
   "sub":
   [
     {
      "name":"Menu 2",
      "url":"menu-2.php"
     }
   ]
  }
]
```

this way i should do

```
array(
    'name'  => 'Menu',
    'sub'   => array(
        array(
            'name'  => 'Menu 2',
            'url'   => 'menu-2.php'
        )
    )
)
```

i am creating json array with this function
Do I have to make a change here? I'm not really good in arrays.

```
<?php
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=propanel_001", "root", "");
    $parent_category_id = "";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tb_sayfalar";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $data = get_node_data($parent_category_id, $connect);
    }
    echo json_encode(array_values($data));
    function get_node_data($parent_category_id, $connect)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tb_sayfalar WHERE parent_id = '".$parent_category_id."'";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        $output = array();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $sub_array = array();
            if (array_values(get_node_data($row['id'], $connect))) {
                $sub_array['name'] = $row['page_name']; 
                $sub_array['sub'] = array_values(get_node_data($row['id'], $connect));
            }else{
                $sub_array['name'] = $row['page_name']; 
                $sub_array['url'] = $row['page_url'].".php";
            }
            $output[] = $sub_array;
        }
        return $output;
    }
?>
```

Comment: You need `json_decode` https://3v4l.org/W2sFp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json\_decode to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need, `json_decode($json,true);`

```
<?php
$json = '[{"name":"Menu","sub":[{"name":"Menu 2","url":"menu-2.php"}]}]';
$array = json_decode($json,1);
print_r($array[0]);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/JZQCn

OR use it as a parsable string representation of a variable with [var_export()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

```
<?php
$json = '[{"name":"Menu","sub":[{"name":"Menu 2","url":"menu-2.php"}]}]';
$array = var_export(json_decode($json,1)[0]);
print($array);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/rLA9R

Answer (score 1):

You must use `json_decode` to convert `JSON` representing Object to Associative array.

**Example Code**

**`$resArr = json_decode($response, true);`**

For more information look at [PHP JSON_DECODE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: I need to use json_decode when creating json data, do I understand correctly?

Comment: please, no such thing as a json object, or a json array : json is just a string that represents an object. You can (in php) serialize an object or associative array to a `json string` with json_encode , and deserialize a string (decode) into objects or associative arrays.