# How to decode php json array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to show name and type but not working. How can I do taht?

$json:

```
{"222":{"id":"222","name":"Shirt1","type":"Men","product":"1","count":"2","price":7000},"223":{"id":"223","name":"Shirt2","type":"Men","product":"2","count":"1","price":4000},"224":{"id":"224","name":"Shirt3","product":"3","count":"2","price":14000}}
```

Decode:

```
$products = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($products['id'] as $k => $v)
{
    var_dump(array_key_exists('name', $v));
}
```

Comment: Just `var_dump($products)` works right?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Result: array(1) {
  [221]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "221"
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Shirt"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "Men"
    ["product"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["count"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["price"]=>
    int(7000)
  }
}

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$products = json_decode($json, true);

$result = '';

foreach( $products as $product ) {
   $result .= 'Name : ' . $product['name'] . ', type : ' . $product['type'] . ';';
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: result is : Array
(
    [Shirt] => Men
)

Comment: How Can I show : Name: Shirt , Type: Men

Comment: Please check now.