# Decode multiple json per line from file

Tags: php, arrays, json, extract

We are trying to extract certain information of multiple json objects written into a file. There is one per line, and need to get some strings from each of them and print specific information.

This JSON format is very strange, I would like to know if there is a code to achieve results we need

```
{'creationDate': None, 'endTime': 1563754500.0, 'expirationDate': 1563743700.0, 'isPriorityOffer': False, 'offerId': 'AAGutxx7466', 'offerType': 'NON_EXCLUSIVE', 'rateInfo': {'currency': 'USD', 'isSurge': False, 'priceAmount': 54.0, 'projectedTips': 0.0, 'surgeMultiplier': None}, 'schedulingType': 'BLOCK', 'serviceAreaId': 'dd00ctyy', 'serviceTypeId': 'PuyOplzlR1idvfPkv5138g', 'serviceTypeMetadata': {'nameClassification': 'STANDARD'}, 'startTime': 1563743700.0, 'startingLocation': {'address': {'address1': '', 'address2': None, 'address3': None, 'addressId': None, 'city': None, 'countryCode': None, 'name': None, 'phone': None, 'postalCode': None, 'state': None}, 'geocode': {'latitude': 0.0, 'longitude': 0.0}, 'locationType': None, 'startingLocationName': ''}, 'status': 'OFFERED', 'trIds': None}
{'creationDate': None, 'endTime': 1563754500.0, 'expirationDate': 1563741900.0, 'isPriorityOffer': False, 'offerId': 'AAGutxx8547', 'offerType': 'NON_EXCLUSIVE', 'rateInfo': {'currency': 'USD', 'isSurge': False, 'priceAmount': 63.0, 'projectedTips': 0.0, 'surgeMultiplier': None}, 'schedulingType': 'BLOCK', 'serviceAreaId': '50ade699', 'serviceTypeId': 'PuyOplzlR1idvfPkv5138g', 'serviceTypeMetadata': {'nameClassification': 'STANDARD'}, 'startTime': 1563741900.0, 'startingLocation': {'address': {'address1': '', 'address2': None, 'address3': None, 'addressId': None, 'city': None, 'countryCode': None, 'name': None, 'phone': None, 'postalCode': None, 'state': None}, 'geocode': {'latitude': 0.0, 'longitude': 0.0}, 'locationType': None, 'startingLocationName': ''}, 'status': 'OFFERED', 'trIds': None}
```

I tried this code, but is not working wih that json structure

```
<?

function readJson($File){

  // open the file to with the R flag,
    $Path = fopen($File,"r");

    // if file found,
    if ($Path) {
        $print = '';

            // for each line
            while (($line = fgets($Path)) !== false) {
                $Output = json_decode($line);
                $print .= "Service Area: ".$Output->serviceAreaId."<br/>";
                $print .= "Start time: ".$Output->startTime."<br/>";
                $print .= "Price: ".$Output->priceAmount."<hr>";
            }

        fclose($Path);
    } 

    return $print;
}

echo readJson("logs.txt");

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json\_decode to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array)

Comment: Both JSON line are invalid. You need to use double quotes instead of single quotes. Therefore "None" is an invalid json value.

Comment: All json lines outputted are like that. Any idea to read values from them?

Comment: get whoever writes this pseudo-json to write json, if you can. Otherwise, you will have to write a 'myPseudoJsonDecoder' function.

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, that's not valid JSON.  You must use double quotes for keys and string values.  If you can't change the files then you will need to fix it up:

```
$line = str_replace(["'", "None", "False"], ['"', 0, 0], $line);
$Output = json_decode($line);
```

If you have strings other than `None` and `False` that aren't quoted then you will have to add those to the `str_replace` arrays.  If there aren't set ones (could be anything) then you'll need a regex.  It's easier to change them to an integer than it is to try wrapping them in quotes.

Comment: I've tried this, but still not working.. I added that line with str_replace, but is giving blank results. You can see it running here instakarts.com/panel.php

Comment: https://3v4l.org/5oBWl Also, `priceAmount` is a property under `rateInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your JSON-Strings to a valid JSON:

```
{"creationDate": null, "endTime": 1563754500.0, "expirationDate": 1563743700.0, "isPriorityOffer": false, "offerId": "AAGutxx7466", "offerType": "NON_EXCLUSIVE", "rateInfo": {"currency": "USD", "isSurge": false, "priceAmount": 54.0, "projectedTips": 0.0, "surgeMultiplier": null}, "schedulingType": "BLOCK", "serviceAreaId": "dd00ctyy", "serviceTypeId": "PuyOplzlR1idvfPkv5138g", "serviceTypeMetadata": {"nameClassification": "STANDARD"}, "startTime": 1563743700.0, "startingLocation": {"address": {"address1": "", "address2": null, "address3": null, "addressId": null, "city": null, "countryCode": null, "name": null, "phone": null, "postalCode": null, "state": null}, "geocode": {"latitude": 0.0, "longitude": 0.0}, "locationType": null, "startingLocationName": ""}, "status": "OFFERED", "trIds": null}
```

Also you have to access the price via

```
$print .= "Price: ".$Output->rateInfo->priceAmount."<hr>";
```

On my machine the code is running after changing

Comment: Great, but the output is a curl request response, that's why has that format. Is there a way to turn into a JSON structure with double quotes and replace None to null?

Comment: Yes, for changing the JSON while executing, see the solution of @AbraCadaver

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

I would grab the whole thing and then manipulate with the data. And when you pass it back to the file, do: `json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`, so you have a better overview of your json file.

grabbing data:

```php
    <?php
        $f = fopen($file, "r");
        $fr = fread($f, filesize($file));
        $arr = json_decode($file, true);
        $fclose($f);
    
        // access example
        $arr["username"]["id"];
```

At the moment i am working on a similar project with json and it worked flawlessly for me.

### Links

[json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
[json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)