# How to fetch Array from .json in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have json  document with Indian States[Cities[Area]], similar to the following:

```
{
    "Andaman and Nicobar Islands": [{
            "Port Blair": [
                "Aberdeen Bazaar",
                "Bidhabad Village",
                "Chidiyatapu",
                "Corbyns Cove",
                "Dollygunj",
                "Ferrurgunj",
                "Goalghar",
                "Goodwill Estate",
                "Junglighat",
                "Marine Hill",
                "Phoenix Bay",
                "South Point"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Havelock Island": [
                "Govindnagar Beach",
                "Radhanagar Beach",
                "Vijaynagar Beach"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Neil Island": [
                "Ramnagar",
                "Bharat Pur",
                "Sitapur Beach",
                "Laxmanpur",
                "Neil Kendra"
            ]
        }....
}
```

I want to fetch this array in this format:

```
$stateData['Andaman and Nicobar Islands'] => [
    "Port Blair" => [
        "Aberdeen Bazaar" => "Aberdeen Bazaar",
        "Bidhabad Village" => "Bidhabad Village"
         .
         .
         .
    ]
]
```

and so on...
I have this Json data in a json file and assign the value to a variable $stateData using `$stateData = (array)json_decode(fread($file, filesize(public_path('india_state_city1.json'))));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json\_decode to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array)

Comment: What exactly you want? as `json_decode` is working fine.

Comment: Check this demo of your code. https://paiza.io/projects/KtY-0X5O2Kc4LZSgJmctLQ

Comment: as we can see in the [link](https://paiza.io/projects/KtY-0X5O2Kc4LZSgJmctLQ) json_decode() is returning multidimensional  index array. i want that array as associative which have the key and value with same string.

Comment: I think It needs to implements it with some custom code, is it okay?

Comment: sure, it will be okay

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your json is saved in a variable called **$states**.

```
  foreach (json_decode($states) as $key => $state) {
            foreach ($state as $stateData) {
                foreach ($stateData as $key2 => $city) {
                    foreach ($city as $key3 => $cit) {

                        $res[$key][$key2][$cit] = $cit;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

The output:

[image]

Check the Demo: https://paiza.io/projects/NlK9g5jluy8Lz9kmhMW69Q

Answer (score 0):

i got that you want to make the area array to be associative and the id,value is same.
i f i'm right you can do this :

```
foreach ($stateData['Andaman and Nicobar Islands'] as &$array_1) {
    foreach ($array_1 as &$area_array){
        $formatted_array = [];
        foreach ($area_array as $area){
            $formatted_array[$area] = $area;
        }
        $area_array = $formatted_array;
    }
}
```

Comment: lets say i have $user->city and $user->area, and variables $stateData, $cities, $areas. for $cities array should  be from $cities = $stateData[$user->state] , and for areas $area = $cities[$user->state]

Answer (score 0):

long but simple solution i think

1. in my opinion `json_decode` function will help with second parameter passed as `true`
   because it will convert every inner `object` to `array`
2. by converting to array we can easily use the state,city and area name and if you want ordering even you can do that by key no of array

   ```
   <?php
           $data = '{
                 "Andaman and Nicobar Islands": [
                         {
       "Port Blair": [
           "Aberdeen Bazaar",
           "Bidhabad Village",
           "Chidiyatapu",
           "Corbyns Cove",
           "Dollygunj",
           "Ferrurgunj",
           "Goalghar",
           "Goodwill Estate",
           "Junglighat",
           "Marine Hill",
           "Phoenix Bay",
           "South Point"
       ]
   },
   {
       "Havelock Island": [
           "Govindnagar Beach",
           "Radhanagar Beach",
           "Vijaynagar Beach"
       ]
   },
   {
       "Neil Island": [
           "Ramnagar",
           "Bharat Pur",
           "Sitapur Beach",
           "Laxmanpur",
           "Neil Kendra"
             ]
         }
               ]
     }';
         $indian_states = json_decode($data,TRUE);

          foreach ($indian_states as $stateName=>$statesCities)
                   {
                   echo $stateName;

                   foreach ($statesCities as $citiNo=>$cityAreas)
                          {
                               echo '<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|---'; //comment this line
                               foreach ($cityAreas  as $citiName=>$areas)
                                      {
                                          echo $citiName;

                                          foreach ($areas as $areaName){
                                                     echo "<br     />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|---"; //comment this line                                                 echo $areaName;echo '<br />';
                            }
                        }
                 }
            }

         ?>
   ```

**output**

[image]