# Extracting data from multiple Nested Json using PHP

Tags: php, json, api

Here's the json

```
{"msg":"OK","server_time":"2021-11-19 16:41:22","status":200,"result":{"total_pages":1,"files":[{"download_url":"DOWNLOADLINKHERE1","single_img":"IMAGEURLHERE1","file_code":"CODEHERE1","title":"TITLEHERE1"},{"download_url":"DOWNLOADLINKHERE2","single_img":"IMAGEURLHERE2","file_code":"CODEHERE2","title":"TITLEHERE2"}],"results_total":"2","results":2}}
```

Here's my code

```
$json = json_decode($data);
foreach($json["result"] as $result){
    foreach($result["files"] as $file){
        echo $file["file_code"];
    }
}
```

I want to extract all values from the "file_code". I got an error
**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

I was able get the VALUE of the first one using

```
echo $json->result->files[0]->file_code;
```

Is it possible to use a LOOP for the files[0]?

Comment: So did you check what you're providing as an argument to `foreach`?

Comment: `var_dump($json);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json\_decode to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array)

Comment: I edited the question. The also shortened the json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
foreach($json["result"] as $result){
```

sees `$json['result']` as an object, and so the next line tests for `total_pages["files"]`, which doesn't exist.

Putting both `foreach`'s together solves the problem:

```
$data='{"msg":"OK","server_time":"2021-11-19 16:41:22","status":200,"result":{"total_pages":1,"files":[{"download_url":"DOWNLOADLINKHERE1","single_img":"IMAGEURLHERE1","file_code":"CODEHERE1","title":"TITLEHERE1"},{"download_url":"DOWNLOADLINKHERE2","single_img":"IMAGEURLHERE2","file_code":"CODEHERE2","title":"TITLEHERE2"}],"results_total":"2","results":2}}';

$json = json_decode($data, true);
foreach($json["result"]["files"] as $file)
        print $file["file_code"];
```

[Teh playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/RLlEsKC1O1u7MQyo)

Alternatively, make the JSON `result` into an array, and use object property accessors instead of associative array bindings.

```
$data='{"msg":"OK","server_time":"2021-11-19 16:41:22","status":200,"result":[{"total_pages":1,"files":[{"download_url":"DOWNLOADLINKHERE1","single_img":"IMAGEURLHERE1","file_code":"CODEHERE1","title":"TITLEHERE1"},{"download_url":"DOWNLOADLINKHERE2","single_img":"IMAGEURLHERE2","file_code":"CODEHERE2","title":"TITLEHERE2"}],"results_total":"2","results":2}]}';
$json = json_decode($data);
foreach($json->result as $result){
    foreach($result->files as $file){
        echo $file->file_code;
    }
}
```

[Teh playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/Utkkewq94InQ994O)

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your situation and it turns out that your JSON is invalid. You're missing a `}` at the end.

The reason for not getting an exception is because `json_decode` does not throw an error by default. You can make it do so by adding the `JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR` flag,
read the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more info.

Comment: The provided JSON data is clearly not complete, as `....` is not valid JSON. If the JSON were invalid, questions that are the result of a typo are not on-topic and should not be answered.

Comment: @miken32 With the `....` removed the JSON is still invalid.

Comment: json is already edited and corrected i guess

Comment: Have you tried running the code again with that json?

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect for me. If you have any thoughts please feel free to correct me.

```
$num = count($json->result->files);
echo $num;

for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
    {
echo $json->result->files[$i]->file_code;
    }
```